# Joomla does not redirect to login page with correct redirection parameters

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.6

I have integrated Joomla with a vBulletin and a CPG using jFusion for my upcoming site for Cancer patients .

I have set the login link of vB and CPG as http://fakesite.com/site/index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=Zm9ydW0ucGhw , so that when a user logs into Joomla from that link , he will get redirected back to vB or CPG after a successful login .

This is happening correctly when I login with a correct combination of user credentials , but when I login with a wrong username and password , it just redirects back to vB or CPG without any warning, or prompting to try to login again .

The proper behavior should be =

1. User logs in with incorrect username/pass
2. Gets redirected to Joomla login page with correct login redirect parameter 
   That is , if he was accessing login form with this (index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=Zm9ydW0ucGhw ) he should be redirected to it with the correct value of return parameter .
3. After successful login , he she should would go to vB or CPG .

I am using latest Joomla 1.5.x version .

How can I fix this ?
Please help me out , I've been on many forums , but nobody replies .

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a menu with type external url and point it to forum.php ? Then make this menu visible to only registered users.

Comment: I need to redirect them automatically . Read the post carefully .

Comment: Hi, what I meant is that you set return=<this new menu item> at the url.